# OCP custom templates with CONDITIONALs

Tags: templates, openshift

Good day.

I am trying to create a custom Openshift template loaded into OCP catalog based on our approved deployment objects and pattern. I am able to parameterize the values with default ones but the number of templates is increasing based on the combinations..

For example:

1. app-deploy-with-route
2. app-deploy-without-route

Only different on the above two sets are the route object. Would like to know if I can use conditionals in the openshift template which can help in reducing the number of templates created.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Templates do not support conditions afaik.

However, you can wrap your templates in Helm charts and apply conditions there.

Answer (score 0):

As Ghokun already mentioned, OpenShift Templates do not support conditions, by design. They should only be used for simple templating and not for more complex use cases.

Possible alternatives are:

- [Helm Charts](https://helm.sh/)
- [kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) templates (`oc` supports `oc apply -k` and has an `oc kustomize` command).